# In Install4j - How can I read the version from an external file?

Tags: install4j

I run install4j from the gradle plugin but use the user interface to edit the install4j file. But I find it annoying to always have to manually update my `General Settings -> Application Info -> Version` every time I make a new version. This is stored in a file in our source code already so I want to just read that file to avoid the extra input.

How can I read this file, get the version info, then use that in `General Settings -> Appplication Info -> Version`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest invoking install4j from your build process, install4j supports ant, gradle and maven and can also be invoked with a command line executable.

In that case, you can set the version

- with the `release` attribute of the [ant task](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/ant.html)
- with the `release` attribute of the [gradle task](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/gradle.html)
- by overriding the `release` property of the [maven plugin](http://sonatype.github.io/install4j-support/install4j-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release), the maven plugin automatically uses the version in the POM.
- by passing the `--release` argument to the [command line compiler](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/cli/options.html)

For other things that you want to customize from the build process, you can use compiler variables.

Comment: we use the gradle plugin.

Comment: so what do i put in the .install4j file for application version? will it just be ignored?

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727635/in-install4j-how-can-i-specify-the-apps-version-via-gradle-plugin

Comment: Yes, it will be overwritten by the external value