# In install4j, how can i specify the app's version via gradle plugin?

Tags: gradle, install4j

How do I send the project variables such as "application version" in the install4j gradle plugin?

What happens if there is an Application version specified in the install4j file? Which one will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to how the application version is passed by the gradle plugin, that was answered in

[In Install4j - How can I read the version from an external file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356032/in-install4j-how-can-i-read-the-version-from-an-external-file)

As to which value will be used, anything that is passed externally overrides the values that are defined in the project.